# В DiDOM не получается получить данные

Tags: php, didom

Не получается спарсить ссылку на изображение или просто получить доступ к img или даже к figure
Находит только пустые пробелы. В дочерних элементах тоже их нет
пробовал искать как first(); find(); дочерние, соседние элементы нигде нету. Как можно спарсить ссылку на изображение или получить картинку или что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста

```
$posts = $document->find('.film__picture');
<div class="film__picture">
  <figure>
    <img src="/upload/resize_cache/iblock/590/360_560_1/Dzhoker.jpg" alt="Постер: 
     ДЖОКЕР" title="Постер: Джокер" itemprop="image">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это для того, чтобы получить ссылку на картинку
`$posts =  $document->find('.film__picture')[0]->first('img')->getAttribute('src');`